# Why null is returned instead of a value?

Tags: java, random

I have the following code, and am wondering why null is returned when I run the program and not the actual value? Any help would be appericated.

```
import java.util.Random;


public class TestCard {

    public static String[] possCards = new String[]{"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K", "A"};
    public static String[] possSuits = new String[]{"C", "S", "H", "D"};
    public static Random rand = new Random();
    static String value;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(getcard());
    }


    public static void card() {
        String card = possCards[rand.nextInt(possCards.length)];
        String suit = possSuits[rand.nextInt(possSuits.length)];

       value = card + suit;
    }
    public static String getcard(){
        return value;
    }


}
```

Comment: You never call `card()`..

Comment: Default value of the String is Null. You  never intialize any value to the String

Comment: i think first step of debuggging is to learn to add System.out.println in every method to trace method by method block by block

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because null **is** the value held by value at the time the program is run.

Why should it be any different if you don't call any of the methods that give value a reference, such as `card()`, before calling `getCard()`?

Key thing here is to try to walk through your code mentally step wise to see what it does. Either that or step through your code with a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `getcard()` but never calling `card()`, so `value` is never set.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following portion of your code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getcard()); // printing getCard(), 
                                      //but card() isn't called before it!!
}


public static void card() {
    String card = possCards[rand.nextInt(possCards.length)];
    String suit = possSuits[rand.nextInt(possSuits.length)];

   value = card + suit; // assigning value in card() 
                        //but this function needs to get executed
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call the `card()` function:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        card();
        System.out.println(getcard());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before calling the getcard() you need to call card() to preparing your calculations.

Your code need to look like below.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        card();
        System.out.println(getcard());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also have a static block of code in your `TestCard` that will initialize the `value` for you:

```
static{
    card();
}
```

so you know value to be non null